# Метод расширения для UIElementCollection

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть метод расширения:

```
static public List<TResult> ToList<TResult>(this UIElementCollection c, TResult result) where TResult : class
{
    var l = new List<TResult>();
    foreach (var item in c)
    {
        l.Add((TResult)item);
    }
    return l;
}
```

Но проблема появляется когда вызываю:

```
var l = stack.Children.ToList(CheckBox);
```

`stack` это `StackPanel`. где все его элементы `CheckBox`.

Пишет что `CheckBox` тип, который не допустим в данном контексте.

Как правильно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем вам вообще второй параметр?

```
static public List<TResult> ToList<TResult>(this UIElementCollection c) 
     where TResult : UIElement
{
    var l = new List<TResult>();
    foreach (var item in c)
    {
        l.Add((TResult)item);
    }
    return l;
}
```

Использование

```
var l = stack.Children.ToList<CheckBox>();
```

По большому счету это то же самое, что

```
var l2 = stack.Children.Cast<CheckBox>().ToList();
```

Comment: действительно) у

Comment: @Санитариум но вы же понимаете, что код - по сути эквивалент `var l2 = stack.Children.Cast<CheckBox>().ToList();` ?

Comment: ну посути да так

Comment: просто захотелось сделать так)